# Qlikview REST connector pagination namespaced XML

Tags: rest, xpath, pagination, qlikview

We have a XML file that is on somewebsite and looks in a way like this (confidential parts stripped)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<feed xml:base="https://somewebsite.com/crm/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">  
  <title type="text">Accounts</title>  
  <id></id>  
  <updated>2016-02-04T08:36:56Z</updated>  
  <link rel="self" title="Accounts" href="Accounts" />  
<entry>  
    <title type="text"></title>  
    <updated>2016-02-04T08:36:56Z</updated>  
    <author>  
      <name />  
    </author>  
    <content type="application/xml">  
      <m:properties>  
        <d:Type>A</d:Type>  
        <d:UniqueTaxpayerReference m:null="true" />  
        <d:VATLiability m:null="true" />  
        <d:VATNumber m:null="true" />  
        <d:Website m:null="true" />  
      </m:properties>  
    </content>  
  </entry>  
  <link rel="next" href="https://somewebsite.com/Accounts?$skiptoken=guid'ee6bc390-a8ac-4bbd-8a4d-0a1f04ab9bd3'" />  
</feed>
```

We use the new Rest connector to get the data out of this XML file.
The XML has pagination and every 60 entries you can load the next 60 with the link at the bottom of this xml file.

The problem i have is when, in the REST connector, we want to enable pagination with these setting:

Pagination Type: `Next URL`

**Next URL field path:**

```
/*[name()="feed"]/*[name()="link"][contains(@rel,"next")]/@href
```

It doesn't seem to work...

*side note: the XML file has namespaces so i need to target the elements this way instead of /feed/link/...*

I'm using Xpath syntax to target the link href, but maybe this is not the way to go? Or maybe the REST connector isn't using Xpath syntax?

Really hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it turns out that this seems to be due to a "bug" in the "Qlik REST Connector 1.0" so the pagination doesn't work.

**But there is a fix for it:**

1) Make sure that the Qlik REST Connector 1.0 connect dialog box has the NextUrl set to:

```
      feed/link/attr:href
```

2) When the SQL has been generated after using the SELECT-button and going through the wizard you have to modify the sub-SELECT that reads like this:

.....

```
(SELECT  
"attr:rel" AS "rel",  
"attr:title" AS "title",  
"attr:href" AS href,  
"__FK_link"  
FROM "link" FK "__FK_link"),  
.....
```

On line 05 you will have to remove the text AS href.

So it should look like this:

```
.....  
(SELECT  
"attr:rel" AS "rel",  
"attr:title" AS "title",  
"attr:href",  
"__FK_link"  

FROM "link" FK "__FK_link"),  
....
```

3) Find the LOAD statement that loads from this sub-select with a RESIDENT [MasterREST further down in the load script and make sure that the reference to href is changed to [attr:href] - or else you will get an error message while loading.

Should look like this after the change:

```
[link]:  
LOAD [rel],  
  [title],  
  [attr:href],  
  [__FK_link] AS [__KEY_feed]  
RESIDENT RestConnectorMasterTable  
WHERE NOT IsNull([__FK_link]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
/*[name()='feed']/*[name()='link'][@rel='next']/@href
```

Yours should also work actually, maybe whatever you are using does not agree with double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the solution. I already tried that without luck. I don't even know if the Qlikview REST connector is accepting Xpath... I assume it does because of the less tutorials i find.

Comment: Well, at least it's not the XPath apparently. There is some other issue.