# Qlikview REST connector pagination settings for OData source xml

Tags: rest, pagination, odata, qlikview

I can't seem to get the pagination settings right for the Qlik REST connector getting data from an OData-source. It's publicly available Dutch statistics (CBS).

An example is: https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/odata/37259ned/TypedDataSet
First bit of the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="http://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/OData/37259ned" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <id>https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/OData/37259ned/TypedDataSet</id>
  <title type="text">TypedDataSet</title>
  <updated>2018-06-25T02:00:00+02:00</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="TypedDataSet" href="https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/OData/37259ned/TypedDataSet" />
  <entry>
    <id>https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/OData/37259ned/TypedDataSet(0)</id>
    <category term="Cbs.OData.TData" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="self" href="https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/OData/37259ned/TypedDataSet(0)" />
    <title />
    <updated>2018-06-25T02:00:00+02:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:ID>
        <d:Geslacht>T001038</d:Geslacht>
        <d:RegioS xml:space="preserve">NL01  </d:RegioS>
        <d:Perioden>1960JJ00</d:Perioden>
        <d:BevolkingOp1Januari_1 m:type="Edm.Double">11417254</d:BevolkingOp1Januari_1>
        <d:LevendGeborenKinderen_2 m:type="Edm.Double">238789</d:LevendGeborenKinderen_2>
        <d:LevendGeborenKinderenRelatief_3 m:type="Edm.Double">20.8</d:LevendGeborenKinderenRelatief_3>
        <d:Overledenen_4 m:type="Edm.Double">87486</d:Overledenen_4>
        <d:OverledenenRelatief_5 m:type="Edm.Double">7.6</d:OverledenenRelatief_5>
        <d:Geboorteoverschot_6 m:type="Edm.Double">151303</d:Geboorteoverschot_6>
        <d:TotaalVestiging_7 m:type="Edm.Double">551116</d:TotaalVestiging_7>
        <d:TotaalVestigingRelatief_8 m:type="Edm.Double">48</d:TotaalVestigingRelatief_8>
        <d:Immigratie_9 m:type="Edm.Double">45407</d:Immigratie_9>
        <d:UitAndereGemeente_10 m:type="Edm.Double">505709</d:UitAndereGemeente_10>
        <d:TotaalVertrekInclusiefCorrecties_11 m:null="true" />
        <d:TotaalVertrekInclusiefCoRelatief_12 m:null="true" />
        <d:TotaalVertrekExclusiefCorrecties_13 m:type="Edm.Double">564209</d:TotaalVertrekExclusiefCorrecties_13>
        <d:TotaalVertrekExclusiefCoRelatief_14 m:type="Edm.Double">49.1</d:TotaalVertrekExclusiefCoRelatief_14>
        <d:EmigratieInclusiefAdministratieveC_15 m:null="true" />
        <d:EmigratieExclusiefAdministratieveC_16 m:type="Edm.Double">58226</d:EmigratieExclusiefAdministratieveC_16>
        <d:NaarAndereGemeente_17 m:type="Edm.Double">505983</d:NaarAndereGemeente_17>
        <d:VestigingsoverschotInclusiefCorrecties_18 m:null="true" />
        <d:VestigingsoverschotExclusiefCorrecties_19 m:type="Edm.Double">-13093</d:VestigingsoverschotExclusiefCorrecties_19>
        <d:TotaalSaldoCorrecties_20 m:type="Edm.Double">544</d:TotaalSaldoCorrecties_20>
        <d:SaldoAdministratieveCorrecties_21 m:null="true" />
        <d:SaldoOverigeCorrecties_22 m:null="true" />
        <d:TotaleGroei_23 m:type="Edm.Double">138754</d:TotaleGroei_23>
        <d:TotaleGroeiRelatief_24 m:type="Edm.Double">12.2</d:TotaleGroeiRelatief_24>
        <d:BevolkingOp31December_25 m:type="Edm.Double">11556008</d:BevolkingOp31December_25>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
```

The source gives a maximum of 10000 records per page. I need to get the data on the following page(s) as well.

The last few lines look like this:

```
</entry>
<link rel="next" href="https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/odata/37259ned/TypedDataSet?$skip=10000" />
</feed>
```

I've tried the sollution in this thread: [Qlikview REST connector pagination namespaced XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220354/qlikview-rest-connector-pagination-namespaced-xml)
However this gives me an unlimited number of records. The data-load does not stop at the last record.

Pagination settings used:
**Pagination Type:** `Next URL`
**Next URL field path:** `feed/link/attr:href`

Can anybody help me with the settings?